# How Adam optimizer influence the learning rate?

Tags: deep-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

I read some papers about how `ADAM` optimizer works, and there are some issues which seems that are confusing:

`ADAM` equations are:

[image]

1. In the second formula, we squared the gradient.

   1.1 Why we are doing it ?

   1.2 What is the gain from this squared?

   1.3 Are there any situations that the gradient squared (in the denominator) will give us less performance ?

I read that the disadvantage of **`AdaGrad`** algorithm is that `as the number of iteration becomes very large learning rate decreases to a very small number which leads to slow convergence`

It seems to me that `ADAM` algorithm has the same drawback (at a lower dose): we are dividing the learning rate with the second equation (which has the squared gradient).

With a lot of epochs and iterations the learning rate decreases to a very small number and we will meet the same drawback, no ?

2. Am I wrong ?

`ADAM` uses equations 1 and 2 to tune the learning rate.
On the other hand, I saw some examples using **OneCycleLR** scheduler with ADAM.

3.1 Does it seem that if that 2 algorithms (`ADAM` and `OneCycleLR`) work together to tune the learning rate on the same time, they may collide with each other ?
are they ?

3.2 Is it wrong to use OneCycleLR with `ADAM` ?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the algorithm to answer those questions? https://colab.research.google.com/github/d2l-ai/d2l-en-colab/blob/master/chapter_optimization/adam.ipynb